# What is the maximum possible length/size of a JSON object can pass in POST request using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, request

I reading one file in JavaScript [Not wanting to read at server side because it may take more time to read a data if data is large, it may cause "deadlineException"] , file may contain up to "n" no of records. I want to pass a JSON object in ajax request to server using POST method.

is it possible to send more than 1000 record json object to server using post ajax???

Comment: Why would there be a limit in the file format ? There are many practical limits in involved programs or libs but a *"1000 record json "* sounds pretty small.

Comment: @Juhana yes :) got answer from that link